# Android: Login screen with noHistory and SharePrefs but after exit app it goes back to Login screen

Tags: android, authentication, history, logout, sharedpreferences

I was able to open the app and it starts by opening the login screen and after login it takes you to the `MainActivity`. From `MainActivity` there is no back to login and it would stay in session until logout. But when I exit the app it would go back to the login screen even tho I have a `Sharedpref` which saves the username in session. I added `nohistory=true` in the `manifest`. In `MainActivity` I put Intent `mainactivity.class`(if press back button) this reason was because when I:

```
logout > login > mainactivity
```

And press back button  it would go back to logout screen (login should be okay because of `myhistory=true`). My question is **how can I keep username in session even if the app is exit out**.

Links below doesn't help me much

[What is the correct way of creating a login screen/activity in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859095/what-is-the-correct-way-of-creating-a-login-screen-activity-in-android)

[Prevent showing Login screen after user login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363442/prevent-showing-login-screen-after-user-login)

[How to presist Login credentials and do auto-login in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087385/android-login-screen)

My code

**LOGIN.java**

```
    public class Login extends Activity {
    private EditText etUsername;
    private Button btnLogin;
    private Button btnCancel;
    private TextView lblResult;

    @Override  
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  
    {          
        if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)  
        {             
            this.startActivity(new Intent(Login.this,Login.class));  
        }  
        return true;  
    }  
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            String username = etUsername.getText().toString();

            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putString("username", username);

            if(username.equals("1111")){
                lblResult.setText("Login successful.");

             Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
```

**Logout.java**

```
    public class LogoutActivity extends Activity {
    private Button btnLogout;
    private Button btnCancel;
    private TextView lblResult;
    private EditText code;
    @Override  
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  
    {  
       if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)  
        {  
            this.startActivity(new Intent(LogoutActivity.this,MainActivity.class));  
        }  
        return true;  
    }  

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.logout);

        code = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.codeout);
        btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
        btnCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        lblResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);

        btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String logout = code.getText().toString();

                SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                editor.remove("username");

                if (logout.equals("99999")){
                    lblResult.setText("Logout successful");

                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                } else {
                    lblResult.setText("Logout failed");

                }

            }
        });

         btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Login.onCreate()`, check for the user ID in the SharedPref.  If it exists, go directly to the `MainActivity`.

Comment: one of the link I included in my post did mention that but I cant figure out how to code that check for userID if "username still in session" open MainActivity else open login screen

Comment: If I recall correctly, your user session ends when the user hits Logout.  If that is the case, your "session" can be determined on the sole condition of if that user name exists in the Shared Pref. So, in the `onCreate`, check for the existence of the user name in Shared Pref - if it exists then start up the MainActivity Activity.

Comment: Thanks again Haphazard. Im actually asking for sample code on how to check for existence user name and would like to ask if my Shared Pref coding is correct as shown?

Comment: You have demonstrated that you are able to use Shared Prefs and use Intents to go to other Activities - the existing code looks fine.  To do your user name check, it's as simple as `if(settings.getString("username", null)!=null){Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);  startActivity(i);}`.

Comment: I just added the code you gave me and it still goes to the login screen. Did I put the code in the right place?

Comment: Did you debug/log to see if the Shared Pref was return properly?

Comment: I just looked at the LogCat I didn't see any SharedPref anywhere as I was playing with the app.

Comment: That's not very scientific.  You should set a breakpoint in the code at the line that grabs the Shared Pref to see if anything is returned. If nothing is returned then you may have to add `editor.commit()` below `editor.putString("username", username);`.

Comment: Okay I got it working now. it opens in mainActivity from android homescreen after login and pressing back/home button. I believe this new error is related to sharedprefs. After i logout it would open login screen and if i press cancel or press android home button and reopen the app both result would show error and force close. What could be causing that problem?

Comment: I think it would be better if you opened a new question with the error stack trace and all that.  Glad to hear the login-bypass is working, though!

Comment: @Haphazard
I have another problem which i am sure its related to this. As I logout, opens the login screen, exit the app, and reopen the app, it would open the Mainactivity instead of login screen even though i logout. Im not sure if the code you mentioned works.

`if(settings.getString("username", null)!=null){Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class); startActivity(i);}`

Comment: In Logout, you have to `editor.commit();`  after `editor.remove("username");`

Comment: actually I added that before I put that comment and its still opening the mainActivity instead of login screen after logout

Comment: I can only suggest that you put in breakpoints and launch your app in Debug mode to see why it is failing.  Maybe the SharedPref is "" instead of null?  The debugger is your friend!

Comment: http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html here's a decent intro to debugging in Eclipse.  Don't worry that it's a Java app rather than an Android app - it's all the same.  Just start your application using the `bug` image instead of the `start` image.

Comment: I am familiar with using the debug/logcat but one thing is I dont understand what it means. Im looking under variables with each name and value and also in debug im clueless.

Comment: Not all objects are readable right away. Some have to be dug through to get the details.  You can expand some objects in the Variables screen by clicking the + button beside it. For example, an ArrayList will tell you nothing until you click the + then you get to see each element inside of it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, when is this application due to the client?  It seems to be taking a while to code up!

Comment: When i pointbreak the null line it shows black screen on the device and when i pointbreak startactivity i was able to run the app like normal. it doesn't show much "understandable" result of breakpoint within the null line. As for application due, it would be within a month.

Comment: The screen will load once you exit the `onCreate()` method (or whenever you relinquish control back to the UI by hitting `Resume`). You have effectively stopped the program from running so you are able to inspect the variable values and program state at a certain point in the program execution.      If you put a breakpoint on the `null` check, you can highlight `settings.getString("username", null)` and press Ctrl+i to see what the return value of that method is.  It's actual code executing infront of your eyes!

Comment: thanks! nothing happens when i highlight and press ctrl+i (ctrl and i) by the way i changed the word 'settings' to 'prefs' as my sharedpref code has 'prefs' instead of 'settings' in the login class but in logout class it has 'settings'

Comment: @Haphazard any other advice? =)

Comment: If your two activities cannot see each other's Shared Prefs, you may have to get the Context of one of your activities to the others so they are able to use it in place of `getApplicationContext()`. I'm not sure how you would do it in your case.

Comment: would putting import com.xxx.logout in login class and vice versa makes a diff.?

Comment: Nope.  You actually have to use the instance of the object for it to work (if that's actually the problem).

Answer (score 0):

I have solution check in the application's splash screen user logout or not and there after go into login screen or home screen

```
String unique_id = loginSharedPreferences
                        .getString("UniqueId", "NA");

if (unique_id.equals("")) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Splace_Screen.this,
                                    LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

} else {
   Intent intent = new Intent(Splace_Screen.this,
                                    DrawerActivity.class);
   startActivity(intent);
}
finish();
```